# Controlling power via code?

Tags: control, low-power

I have a lithium battery connected to a 0.33 amp / 12V pump via a connector (which can be changed - this connector option is part of the question). Is it possible to control power to the pump via code running on a Raspberry Pi or some alternative, and what connector would be recommended?

The reason behind my question is that I need to be able to power and unpower(?) the pump automatically, hence the need for code.

If it is possible, what avenues can I pursue to build a practical solution? If relevant, the main concerns, in order of priority, are: weight, complexity (number of independent components, complexity of code and dependencies), and power consumption (efficiency).

Comment: I suggest you take the simple path and buy a relay module. Google one of the chinese webshops and you'll find plenty that are meant to be used with an arduino. Check that it accepts 3V input, most will. Alternatively, a BJT transistor or or MOSFET will do, but that is a little bit more involved.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen 3V input? I presume this is input from the Pi then, and not the pump power supply?

Comment: Yes, the 'control' input. The 'power' input for such modules is often 12V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controlling the power going to the load can be done using various ways the design usually depends on the concept of the driver,**it also depend upon the current your pump drives**

***There is always a need to isolate reactive loads in your circuit as the have reflective power hence there always a chance that the power may flow back to PS damaging any controlling unit in the way***

Using the Raspberry pi you could use relay(ON/OFF) as Wouter van Ooijen suggests
or you could use a DAC to get a range of analog output to derive the pump,by varying the voltage across the pump.
you will need to bias the pump and vary this biasing voltage using the DAC output to give variable speed to the pump.

---

Or you could just you a simple analog solution ,where you can use a H bridge which can be unbalanced using a POT resistance,you can relate this value POT in a form of feedback hence relating it with some of the control variable like speed(rpm),or temperature in cooling application.

---

Also you can use a PWM circuit as Scott says with a 555 timer,to drive the pump,change the duty cycle to adjust the rpm.

Comment: PWM is often a better option than a DAC, as you'll need driver circuitry anyway, and that will be more complex with an analog input.  Pumps/Motors are inherently low pass, as well, wo PWM is fine.

Comment: yeah,you need to vary resistances to change duty cycle ,as OP wanted a `MCU` controlled answer,I advised using DAC,rest PWM is the cheap solution,also it saves battery power.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't have any electronics knowledge, but rather I'm a software engineer. According to the pump seller, PWM as well as varying the voltage can't be used as both will merely result in insufficient output pressure. Therefore I'm planning on simply having full power turned on and off at regular intervals. Does a H bridge work for this, and are there any simpler alternatives?

Comment: @MaMba, you don't need to change resistances to change the duty cycle -- you use a PWM peripheral which uses timers to change the duty cycles on most MCU's

Comment: For example, https://penoff.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/led-pwm-dimmer-with-pic12f629/ uses a PIC12F629, $1.29 each in quants of 1, to use PWM to dim LEDs. The circuit uses 3 yoked dig outs, but that shouldn't be necessary with the right driver. Add a power driver, and the same program will handle a pump.  You can configure one of the unused pins as an ADC to read a pot, and your that to control duty cycle (pump speed), or use any other method, like buttons for increase and decrease.

Comment: Thanks for the leads in any case @MaMba and everyone else. I'll have to investigate these in more depth but it's looking like the relay is my best bet for now. I'll accept this answer tomorrow if no others come up.

Comment: @ScottSeidman there is a need to change the resistances in case with 555 timer,other wise in case using a MCU (like PIC) then the circuit wont remain truly analog and simple.Of course many things can be done in various ways but we have to answer according to OP.

Comment: He needs a driver regardless of whether he uses a DAC or a MCU.  To control the DAC, he needs an MCU.  The driver is simpler for PWM vs a DAC (it's on/off).

Comment: Alright, so I'm going to use the relay as that appears to be the simplest solution. I'll accept this answer.